# I need a RHEL 6.7 based template where Oracle 12C R1 is installed in it

Tags: oracle12c

Trying to create a RHEL 6.7 image with ORACLE 12C R1 installed in it.

1. I am trying to create a RHEL 6.7 template where i need "ORACLE 12c R1" should be installed in it. But via command line i cannot able to install it, because the installer script needs GUI. All the docs/videos i found so far involves GUI installer(No CLI).

So in virtualbox i created RHEL 6.7 Official version(GUI), and installed Oracle 12C R1 and its works fine.

Now i tried to convert the ".VDI" format of that VM to ".ISO" so that i can use that template on any cloud provider. I used different commands to do this,

1. dd
2. mkisofs
3. VBoxManage

But after conversion the image is not bootable. Is there any way to convert the VDI to ISO ?

2. Can we install ORACLE 12c R1 on "RHEL 6.7" via Command Line completely ? If yes, then i can do this on any cloud provider and create a template out of it.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: [Read about silent mode installation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/122/HPDBI/installing-and-configuring-oracle-database-using-response-files.htm#HPDBI-GUID-D53355E9-E901-4224-9A2A-B882070EDDF7).

Comment: Yes, I read about it and installed. Thanks Alex.